# Apps for Office: my task pane app doesn't get the licensing '?et=' license token

Tags: ms-office, apps-for-office

MSDN docs say:

> The Office application calling you app's URL would add the following query
> string to it and then pass the URL: http://fooservice.com/index.htm?et=
> PAByAD4APAB0ACAAYQBpAGQAPQ .... (->this string goes on for a while - Mihaly KR)

### I've tried everything, but nothing gets ever POSTed (or GETted), no `?et` parameter.

The app loads fine in Office, but I want to get the client id from the token, so I could do a permanent storage on my server.
I did a php page which prints all get and post parameters, and set it as the APP source, so I can see, what is getting posted.

My manifest file `taskpaneapp.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>08afd7fe-1631-42f4-84f1-5bc51e242f98</Id>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>EN-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Get token"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Test app for getting token"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue=
    "http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/_layouts/images/general/office_logo.jpg"/>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Document"/>
    <Capability Name="Workbook"/>
  </Capabilities>
  <DefaultSettings>    
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://taskpaneapp.misc.dev.nomo.hu/print_r.php"/>    
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

My token file `taskpaneapp.tok`

```
<r>
  <t 
    aid="WA900006056" 
    pid="{08afd7fe-1631-42f4-84f1-5bc51e242f98}" 
    cid="32F3E7FC559F4F49" 
    did="{0672BAE9-B41B-48FE-87F1-7F4D3DD3F3B1}" 
    ts="30" 
    et="Trial" 
    ad="2012-01-12T21:58:13Z" 
    ed="2012-06-30T21:58:13Z" 
    sd="2012-01-12T00:00:00Z" 
    te="2012-06-30T02:49:34Z" />
  <d>VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZl/YFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=</d>
</r>
```

MSDN docs are inconsistent on the token file schema, some use `{}`s in pid and did some does not. I've tried both, none of them worked.

my registry entry is:

```
key: taskpaneapp
value: \\NOMONAS\....\taskpaneapp.xml
```

I tried

```
key: entry1
value: \\NOMONAS\.....\taskpaneapp.xml
```

too, it didn't work.

Are the MSDN docs outdated? Don't think so, they were updated in Febr, 2014 and are said to be compatible with Office Apps JS API 1.0 and 1.1

#### Anyone having the same issues?

Please help me if you have any suggestions, or faced the same problems. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

---

**update 1:** So I figured out that token file is successfully read by Office.

When setting license status to "Trial", a notification appears on the top left corner of the task pane app when started. MSDN documentation is very confusing, [here it says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163880(v=office.15).aspx), that token file pid param must be in brackets, [here it is used without brackets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123519(v=office.15).aspx). After a lot of trial and error, it turns out that token file is only read if the pid *is* in brackets.

Bottom line, I changed my .tok file to have `pid="{08afd7fe-1631-42f4-84f1-5bc51e242f98}"`  in it. I guess I'll take the Token Schema page to be true, so I changed the cid and aid attributes to also include `{}`-s.

But I still don't get the `?et` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is an Office bug (duh).
In this [forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeapps/en-US/7c4bbe52-0038-42ea-8778-a9dc4db79e68/test-license-key-in-visual-studio?forum=appsforoffice), microsoft official says the following:

> After my research it seems that this is a "known issue" with Office 15
>   SP1 because of which apps loaded from the registry are not getting et
>   returned as expected.

Workaround:

put the `?et` get parameter right into your xml, and forget everything MSDN docs told you about the .tok file and editing the registry.

`<SourceLocation DefaultValue= “http://myofficeapp.com?et=<base64 encoded token>”`

For your convenience, here is a sample token string from MSDN docs

```
http://myApp/index.htm?et=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%2bAA%3d%3d
```