# Cannot Add License Check to Office 365 Addin

Tags: javascript, node.js, office365, office-addins

My friend and I have run into two different sets of issues while attempting to add licensing to an Office 365 Excel addin, and have so far not been able to resolve it through any docs or forums.

We followed the instructions here: https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/add-license-checks-to-office-and-sharepoint-add-ins to the letter, and have created a node/express server to host the app, and are using the REST verification service to determine the token's authenticity.

We've been testing on 2 different machines, and the issues we've ran into are as follows:

1) We cannot get the test license to return isTest: true 
2) (on the other machine) The token never gets appended to the initial get call, at all.

The closest we've come to finding a solution so far was this SO post: [Nodejs - Office App License token verification service does not validate the token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890933/nodejs-office-app-license-token-verification-service-does-not-validate-the-tok), who seems to have this issue, but whose question is unanswered. Or this one, [Apps for Office: my task pane app doesn't get the licensing '?et=' license token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991609/apps-for-office-my-task-pane-app-doesnt-get-the-licensing-et-license-token), whose answer suggest appending a sample one to the xml file.

We've also replicated this issue on other tester's machines as well, but have not been able to find a solution for this anywhere.